# javascript detect window.location.hash on <a> click

Tags: javascript

```
<script>
if(window.location.hash){
    var x = location.hash;
        if(x == '#abc'){alert(x);}
}
</script>

<a href="#abc">Clikc me</a>
```

I need detect when user click `<a>` if hash is correct, will do something...

When I click `<a href="#abc">Clikc me</a>` its not working.

it only works when I enter testing.php#abc on url bar

Comment: Can't you use onclick event for <a>

Comment: can you please elaborate your question?

Comment: This doesn't work because clicking that link doesn't actually cause the page to reload. It just scrolls it to the location with ID `abc` (if there is such a location).

Comment: i have a div id='abc' I need to detect the id and load(); content into this div, thats why i need to detect the value of #

Comment: As I understand, you want to know the hash value when a user clicks. But since no event is attached to the click, that particular code will not get executed when the user clicks a. Hence plz use <a href="#abc" onclick="myFunc()">Clikc me</a> and place your check inside the myFunc() function. Further, if you want to get the value of href; give onclick="myFunc(this)"; and in the function myFunc(param) { //Access href attr as param.href }.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should bind your javascript with an onclick event , that is to be performed on when any anchor tag is pressed. 
so that when user click on any event it will execute javascript code.

```
var Anchors = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

for (var i = 0; i < Anchors.length ; i++) {
        Anchors[i].addEventListener("click", 
        function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();


            if(this.href == '#abc'){alert(this.href);}

        }, 
        false);
}
```

Comment: May I please ask how to do it?